# Ubuntu virtual box not starting properly

Tags: boot, virtualbox

I have a windows7 PC on which I have installed virtualbox (5.2). I have downloaded the 19.04 ubuntu image and installed this in virtual box. Now when I boot up the VM, ubuntu starts, but it blocks in the loading screen with the moving dots... When I pause the VM and unpause it, the boot continues and the login screen appears.

Does anybody have an idea of why it isn't booting properly? When I shutdown the VM and Ubuntu boots in secure mode (i guess that is what it is called) the block appears after the "Started GNOME display manager" entry. Again, when I pause and unpause the VM it sometimes continues, however not always. Sometimes it is just stuck forever.

I have tried different Ubuntu images (18.04) and different versions of virtualbox. Both don't seem to fix the problem.

Comment: Hi, do you have Hyper-V or VT-d enabled in your BIOS or not? (btw your pause-unpause method is wrong, never has anyone ever heard ot this and it's likely that waiting it out would be just as effective)

Comment: The VT-d is enabled. Can't find anything about Hyper-V. (btw the pause-unpause method really does work. Waiting for 15 minutes has no effect, while the pause-unpause immidiately fixes the problem)

Comment: what I'm trying to say is that it is not a fix, it's a fluke that this exits out of the blockage and this means that nobody can draw useful information from that. try downloading a new virtualbox and a new ubuntu 19.04. also increase the ram and graphical memory you alot to it. maybe also give it a second cpu before you try and install the virtual machine.

Comment: @Frank - what does the VBox.log (of the VM) show?